# How to connect React Native and PostgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, react-native

Hey guys I have a question regarding React Native and PostgreSQL.

I've build a rn App where you can save data like hours, project and a comment and another screen where you can load it. It is a project for my workplace where we have an intern timemanagement system. Our database is a PostgreSQL database.

My question is how do I connect to our database ? 
- I have a test DB running locally on my pc, I would like to connect to it first.

I did some research and found that I need to use fetch request.
Then I found out that there are two approaches (kinda):

1.node-postgres npm package (my Q: Do I need to know how to write in NodeJS?)

2.postgraphile GraphQL (my Q: Is it easier to do it with GraphQL? Do I need to be a GraphQL expert?)

I really appreciate any response or tipps you can give me. 
Sincerly Faded.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to expose your data with an API, with nodejs and node-postgres for example.

Comment: Okay so I need to Fetch the data and I use node-postgres package with it. Would you say I need to start a course or tutorial on NodeJS in generall or could I handle it by just following the docs of node-postgres?

Comment: It would be better for you to follow a course on NodeJS (if you don't know it at all) and a Web/API framework (Express for example).

Comment: It's so dumb that we need a third program to connect the two.